# Should a ngSubmit function call have a return statement in order to trigger the $digest cycle at the right time?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

Say we have the following simple form:

```
<form ngSubmit="doSomething()">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

<form>
```

And in the controller:

```
var ctrl = this;

ctrl.doSomething = function () {

    // Anything can happen here

}
```

I know the digest cycle is triggered by `ngSubmit`, but how does Angular know *when* to run the digest cycle? Is it run after `doSomething()` is complete, and if so how does angular know that `doSomething()` has indeed completed because I haven't seen any examples of `ngSubmit` functions using a `return` statement? e.g.

```
ctrl.doSomething = function () {

    // Anything can happen here

    // Add return statement so that angular knows callback is complete perhaps?
    return;

}
```

The reason I ask is because within my own `doSomething()` function I'm updating a scope value e.g. `ctrl.myValue++`. The updated value is being updated/reflected in the model fine but I don't understand how, or rather *when*, angular is able to ascertain that `doSomething()` has finished and it's now time to safely start the digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

> I know the digest cycle is triggered by ngSubmit

Yes, `ngSubmit` directive like `ngClick` triggers digest cycle

> I haven't seen any examples of ngSubmit functions using a return statement?

Please read more about [Scope Life Cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

> "... assignment such as $scope.username="angular" will not immediately cause a $watch to be notified, instead the $watch notification is delayed until the $digest phase. This delay is desirable, since it coalesces multiple model updates into one $watch notification as well as guarantees that during the $watch notification no other $watches are running. **If a $watch changes the value of the model, it will force additional $digest cycle.**"

So when you call `ctrl.myValue++`, the model changes and it fires digest cycle

> Add return statement so that angular knows callback is complete perhaps?

No, I don't think so and this approach has not mentioned in Angular [DOCs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

Comment: "So when you call ctrl.myValue++, the model changes and it fires digest cycle". This is the root of my confusion. `ctrl` is assigned to `this` which refers to a simple object on the controller. So how can angular know that a manual update of one of the objects properties (e.g. `ctrl.myValue++`) has occurred, unless the dirty checking is carried out periodically?

Comment: @Iamme Angular has deep watcher that checks all data under scope per digest cycle run.